# Passing argument from a shell script to a new session

Tags: linux, usb, typescript

I'm writing a script to log serial data from an USB port to file and I'm using `script` and `picocom` to log the data as such:

```
sudo script -a -c 'sudo picocom /dev/ttyUSB0 | ts "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S10"' /usr/local/logs/device1.log
```

which works ok and I want to wrap it in an `openPort` script so I can call `openPort device1 USB0`. So far I've got

```
sudo script -a -c 'sudo picocom /dev/tty"${2}" | ts "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S10"' /usr/local/logs/${1}.log
```

which unfortunately doesn't open the COM port. I think the problem is that `script` launches a new session which executes `sudo picocom /dev/tty"{2}"` instead of using the argument passed from `openPort`. Is there a way to pass the argument properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything inside single quotes is not expanded, so just remove this parameter from the quotes:

```
sudo script -a -c 'sudo picocom /dev/tty'"${2}"' | ts "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S10"' /usr/local/logs/${1}.log
```

Shell will take care of merging all parts together.